# Is shear transformation doesn't have enough eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am doing MSc. in Machine learning and AI . I had finished my last class of math was in 2002, so I am sorry to ask basic question .

In some of documentation it says eigenbasis doesn't exist for a shear type of transformation since there  are not enough eigenvectors .  What  does the word enough means here ?

In some of documentation say's shear results full of vectors  on to the lines of x-axis. Is it not enough due to the fact that   there is no diagonal line to transform a "change in basis"  ?

I am bit confused. please help me

Comment: If you work in 2D, do you mean a transformation with matrix $\binom{1 \ a}{0 \ 1}$? What about 3D ?

Answer (score 1):

The correct mathematical formulation is that, is $a \ne 0$, the matrix of a shear

$$S_a=\begin{pmatrix}1 & a\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

isn't diagonalizable, i.e. cannot be written under the form:

$$S_a=P\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1 & 0\\0 & \lambda_2\end{pmatrix}P^{-1}\tag{1}$$

[had (1) been possible, the columns of $P$ would provide 2 independant eigenvectors].

In such a case, indeed, the only eigenvectors are of the form $\binom{k}{0}$.